# Golang encryption ciphertext has padding of As in the beginning

Tags: encryption, go

I'm trying to use a custom IV for encryption but it results in a ciphertext with padding of As in the beginning like

`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACbglBtdgH3ajX1jgkOaVAsFYyDxRRI=`

I followed the sample implementation at https://gist.github.com/manishtpatel/8222606 with a few changes. The go playground to run and test https://play.golang.org/p/2rS6zBwbnF

My code is at
https://play.golang.org/p/qlx_cU0VPQ

Here is the encrypt function for references as well

```
func Encrypt(key []byte, text string) string {
    // key := []byte(keyText)
    plaintext := []byte(text)

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // The IV needs to be unique, but not secure. Therefore it's common to
    // include it at the beginning of the ciphertext.
    ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))
    iv := commonIV

    stream := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
    stream.XORKeyStream(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], plaintext)

    // convert to base64
    return base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(ciphertext)
}
```

Comment: Where did you find this example?

Comment: Add the code to the question.

Comment: You literally wrote in your code that it's common to include the IV in the ciphertext, but you don't include it in the ciphertext. The As are base64 encoded 0s

Comment: This is a good example of where when dealing with bytes, not strings, a hexadecimal encoding is much more useful: `0000000000000000000000000000000026E0941B5D807DDA8D7D6382439A540B056320F14512`

Answer (score 3):

See this example for golang aes encryption, if you don't need to use AES CFB specifically you could just swap out your encrypt function and use GCM instead. ***TL;DR- Copy & paste your crypto code from this link instead of Stack Overflow.***

https://github.com/gtank/cryptopasta/blob/master/encrypt.go

If you're just learning watch the associated talk and read the code linked, if you're actually encrypting with this, use the linked code.

- [Video on Go crypto](https://golangnews.com/stories/1469-video-crypto-for-go-developers-gophercon-crypto)
- [Repo with vetted crypto examples](https://github.com/gtank/cryptopasta)

PS I'm no expert but your iv should be random each time shouldn't it? To fix your code above you need to copy the iv/nonce in with something like:

copy(ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize], iv[:])

the idea is the unique random nonce is at the start of ciphertext, and used to decrypt (so commonIV shouldn't exist) this stops it producing the same output for the same cleartext. Note how your code when fixed produces the same output each time - that's bad.

But **please**, don't use advice from people on stack overflow for crypto, and certainly not from me, see the links here instead, and heed the instructions. This stuff is too hard to work out by trial and error.

Comment: Yes, the IV should be random for each encryption. Also CFB mode is not a frequent mode choice.

Comment: In some Ciphers IV is IV : {0,1}^m of a fixed length defines blocks length where x = x1 || x2 || .. || xm and |xi| = m. In some ciphers IV has just value 0, so,  {0}^m.

Comment: The only issue with GCM mode is that is is still not common across platforms, other than that is is a great choice.